# Inserting Tables into Latex

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, align

I have this problem that anytime I want to insert a Table into my latex document, it gives me an error: I don't know what I did wrong. I would appreciate if someone can help me. I went through the threads to get a solution but to avail. Please assist me.

I'm using this document class:

```
\documentclass[12pt,bibtotoc,liststotoc,BCOR5mm,DIV12]{book}
```

Packages I used:

```
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{bibgerm}            
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}            
\usepackage{url}                
\usepackage{listings, color}


\usepackage{subfig}                     
%\usepackage{scrpage2}          
\usepackage{fancyhdr}         
\usepackage{lipsum}            
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{ftnxtra}
\usepackage{fnpos}


\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
%\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true
    ,breaklinks
    ,ngerman
    ]{hyperref} 
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}  

\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1}         
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.9}     
\definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.9}     
\usepackage{cite}                      
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 
\usepackage{longtable}         
\usepackage{bigstrut}         
\usepackage{enumerate}        
\usepackage{microtype}
```

Table:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
 Acquisition Date & 06/03/1985 \\ \hline 
Product & \multicolumn{1}{l}{TM L1T} \\ \hline
 Quality & 9 \\ \hline Cloud Cover & 30\% \\ \hline
 LMAX_Band 6 & 15.303 \\ \hline
 LMIN_band 6 & 1.238 \\ \hline
 QCALMAX_Band 6 & 255 \\ \hline
 QCALMIN_band 6 & 1 \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}% 
\caption{A new table}
 \label{tab:table1}% 
\end{table}%
```

Error:

```
! Missing # inserted in alignment preamble.
<to be read again>
\cr
l.123 \begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
There should be exactly one # between &'s, when an
\halign or \valign is being set up. In this case you had
none, so I've put one in; maybe that will work.
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate
l.124 Acquisition Date &
06/03/1985 \\ \hline
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate
l.125 Product &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{TM L1T} \\ \hline
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate
l.126 Quality &
9 \\ \hline
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate
l.127 Cloud Cover &
30\% \\ \hline
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate
l.128 LMAX\_Band 6 &
15.303 \\ \hline
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate
l.129 LMIN\_band 6 &
1.238 \\ \hline
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate
l.130 QCALMAX\_Band 6 &
255 \\ \hline
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate
l.131 QCALMIN\_band 6 &
1 \\ \hline
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you show us the code of the table as well, not just the error?\

Comment: Thank you http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%c3%b8rn-t for the response :). Here is the code below:

Comment: \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
    Acquisition Date & 06/03/1985 \\ \hline
    Product & \multicolumn{1}{l}{TM L1T} \\ \hline
    Quality & 9 \\ \hline
    Cloud Cover & 30\% \\ \hline
    LMAX\_Band 6 & 15.303 \\ \hline
    LMIN\_band 6 & 1.238 \\ \hline
    QCALMAX\_Band 6 & 255 \\ \hline
    QCALMIN\_band 6 & 1 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    \caption{A new table}
  \label{tab:table1}%
\end{table}%

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  You should edit your question to add the code and make it in to a complete minimal document demonstrating the problem, see [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Comments are really not the best place for code, much better if you edit your question. I did it for you now, but in the future much better if you do it yourself.

Comment: To typeset an underscore character in text mode, you mustn't just write `_`; instead, write `\_`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  thank you for the info (I'm new to the platform) and Mico  I did that but still have no result. My head is crashing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some fixes the code of the question works:

```
\documentclass[12pt,bibtotoc,liststotoc,BCOR5mm,DIV12]{scrbook}

\begin{document}    
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
 Acquisition Date & 06/03/1985 \\ \hline
 Product & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{TM L1T} \\ \hline
 Quality & 9 \\ \hline Cloud Cover & 30\,\% \\ \hline
 LMAX\_Band 6 & 15.303 \\ \hline
 LMIN\_band 6 & 1.238 \\ \hline
 QCALMAX\_Band 6 & 255 \\ \hline
 QCALMIN\_band 6 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\caption{A new table}
 \label{tab:table1}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Fixes:

- If default behavior of `_` is to start a subscript in math mode. Therefore, it throws an error in text mode. An underscore can be set with `\textunderscore` or `\_` in text mode.
- The vertical line at the end of the second row was missing.
- A small space between number and unit `30\,\%`.

**Update:**

The problem can be reproduced with the two packages `tabu` and `fntxtra`.
If at least one of them is not needed, then remove the unneeded package. Otherwise, a different loading order can be tried:

```
\usepackage{fntxtra}
\usepackage{tabu}
```

The error message is gone, but I have not tested or analyzed, whether both packages are working correctly in this order.

Comment: This worked for you. Great work! but it doesn't work for me. Don't know what's wrong with my latex. I even copied directly the code you shown and when I re-run, I had the same problem. Will it be too many packages for Tables?

Comment: @littlejesus Generate a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). It will show the problematic packages. If you do not need them, remove them, otherwise you have a small compete document for the question.

Comment: Please the packages I used are shown (edited) also I edited the document class from {scrbook} to {book} - sorry!- this was what I used. Do I need to take some of the packages relating to table away?  I have re-run the code you provided but it seems there is a hidden error my eyes cannot see..Can you please perform a magic for me? My head is crushing trying to find solution

Comment: @littlejesus See updated answer.

Comment: ITS WORKING NOW! YOU ARE THE BEST. Great Work!!!!!!. I took the 2 packages out and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause of the (admittedly nearly indecipherable) error messages is that you're loading the package `ftnxtra`. Unless you have a really good reason for loading this package -- e.g., is your document typeset mainly in Farsi? -- you shouldn't be loading this package.

There's a second mistake in the preamble: If, as seems to be likely given some of the other comments you've posted, you actually use `scrbook` rather than `book` as the document class, you shouldn't be loading the `scrpage2` package either.

You really ought to re-examine the need for many of the packages you load. Also, there's no valid excuse for loading a package more than once. Incidentally, do you really mean to turn off hyphenation globally? Why?!

Finally, if you need to typeset an underscore character, you should write `\_`, not `_`. (You probably learned, at some point, that `_` is a "special" character for TeX and that it is used to initiate subscripts in math mode.)
Heiko's earlier answer also mentions this point.